# "Remember me" option for Silverlight login

Tags: silverlight

I created a custom login page for the silverlight navigation application so now I need to set the "remember" me option for the saving username in cookie.

Could anyone guide me please?

Comment: I'm working on a SL5 o-o-b app, and save username/password (encrypted) in isolated (local) storage. When the app starts, it looks in local storage to see if the user saved their credentials, and uses them if found.

Comment: Hi,   With the help of Isolated storage I solved the problem.thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful to other people if you posted the answer. Also, it'd give you rep!

Comment: @It'sNotALie. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/state-management-in-silverlight-4-0-using-isolation-storage/ this one perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsolatedStorage` for this.

Help links:

- [Link one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/working-with-isolated-storage-in-silverlight/)
- [Link two](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/state-management-in-silverlight-4-0-using-isolation-storage/)